# css position absolute and fixed not working propoerly

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

There is a siderbar and we **do not** want it to scroll. So clearly either `position:fixed` or `position:absolute` should do the trick, but they don't!

The following happens with `position:fixed`:

the sidebar glitches on scroll and breaks up and just acts oddly

The following happens with `position:absolute`:

the sidebar scrolls rather than staying in place.

Here is the css for the sidebar (not correct id name)

```
#sidebar{
font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif; 
position: fixed; 
margin-top:80px; 
margin-left:1020px;
font-size:18px;
padding-top:0px; 
padding-bottom:17px; 
text-align:center; 
height:420px; 
width:300px; 
overflow:hidden;
solid #000000;
color:#000000;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
background-color:transparent;
opacity: 1;
z-index:999;
}
```

[this is a link to the blog](http://honkeh.tumblr.com/) so you can maybe check with developer tools to see the glitching and what exactly is happening.

Why is the positioning acting so odd, and how can that be fixed?

And this happens in safari and chrome, I do not have firefox or internet explorer installed, so I am not sure the response for those browsers

picture of glitch, splits sidebar image up and occasionally will show some of the text:

[image]

Comment: I promise css positions are working correctly.

Comment: then why is the sidebar glitching on `position:fixed`

Comment: Seems to work for me. When I scroll down the sidebar stays visible. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: what are you trying to have fixed? is it the right sidebar or left? (I'm assuming right, but just want to make sure)

Comment: @EnigmaRM: oh, yes it's the right sidebar, the one that glitches when you scroll

Comment: @sbooob: make sure you are looking at the sidebar on the right. I am going to post a picture of what happens to the sidebar when I scroll

Comment: Do you have that in the `<center>` tag? I'd suggest using a `<div>` instead. And then use CSS to center align your text, etc. Also, make the `<div>` not a direct child of `body`. Who knows what it is inheriting from your vulgar `<div id="F$#%">`. And get rid of that `alert` when I right click on your screen. It's easier to inspect elements if I can right click. ha

Comment: I'm getting several javascript errors on your page, you should fix them first of all. Secondly, the way position:absolute behaves is correct, it's positioning according to its next positioned parent (not static), not the viewport/browser, position:fixed however, does.

Comment: okay, so then why is position:fixed glitching like that? and where are the javascript errors?

Comment: http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js is sending an error on GET in  analytics.html, you could probably debug it better yourself if you turned off that horrible right-click-prevention

Comment: this is not my site, I just asked permission for passwords so I can remove what you guys need...right click has been removed

Comment: and I cannot edit the analytics thing, that seems to actually be a tumblr add-on that tumblr adds to all blogs because it's not in the original code, but it is in the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from the element with the four-letter F-word.

```
#???? {
    font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 1020px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 420px;
    width: 300px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/ <---- remove for "glitch" to go away
    color: #000000;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

The element is named a censored (I assume) F word!

Comment: Thank you!! Just curious, do you know why that fixes it? And I do apologize for the name of that element, the blog is not mine, and the code for that sidebar was not written by me, I was just asked to help and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Excellent question, it seems the issue comes when you put a Flash element inside an element with `position:fixed;` and `overflow:hidden;` - apparently it's something to do with the chrome native plugin: `PPAPI` (Pepper Plugin API) -- read more (not a lot though): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI#PPAPI

Answer (score 0):

You want the css overflow property: [Overview](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/). Hidden or visible should do the trick.

Comment: if you look at the css, `overflow:hidden` is in it